# Sorting Street fields in magento 2.4

Tags: magento2.4, address, sort, reorder, street

I am with a need to reorder 03 street fileds in the following order in shipping, billing, and customer address forms.

```
street[2] - first
street[1] - second
street[0] - third
```

I could reorder other fields, but could not find the proper way to reorder individual street fields.

Can someone please guide me to the proper implementation for that?

Thanks and Best Regards

Indunil

Answer (score 0):

You can change the street input sort order using a plugin for Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor:

```
class Reorder
{
    public function afterProcess($subject, $jsLayout)
    {
        $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
        ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']
        ['children']['street']['sortOrder'] = 200;

        return $jsLayout;
    }
}
```